# Resize and move rectangles drawn on canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

I am allowing the user to draw rectangles on an image. At the same time , the user should be able to resize or move any of the rectangles at any point of time. 
With some help, i have been able to draw the rectangles but i am unable to come up with resizing and moving part of it. 
The rectangles that are being drawn do not overlap one another and the same has to be validated while resizing and moving too. 
I am using javascript and jquery. 
This is a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5koLdpt2/4/) of what i have done so far :

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

var canvasOffset = $("#canvas").offset();
var offsetX = canvasOffset.left;
var offsetY = canvasOffset.top;

var startX;
var startY;
var isDown = false;

ctx.strokeStyle = "lightgray";
ctx.lineWidth = 3;


function handleMouseDown(e) {
mouseX = parseInt(e.clientX - offsetX);
mouseY = parseInt(e.clientY - offsetY);

// Put your mousedown stuff here
startX = mouseX;
startY = mouseY;
isDown = true;
}

function handleMouseUp(e) {
mouseX = parseInt(e.clientX - offsetX);
mouseY = parseInt(e.clientY - offsetY);
$("#uplog").html("Up: " + mouseX + " / " + mouseY);

// Put your mouseup stuff here
isDown = false;
}

function handleMouseMove(e) {
mouseX = parseInt(e.clientX - offsetX);
mouseY = parseInt(e.clientY - offsetY);

// Put your mousemove stuff here
if (!isDown) {
    return;
}

ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

        drawRectangle(mouseX, mouseY);


}

function drawRectangle(mouseX, mouseY) {
var width = mouseX - startX;
var height = mouseY - startY;
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.rect(startX, startY, width, height);
ctx.stroke();
}


$("#canvas").mousedown(function (e) {
handleMouseDown(e);
});
$("#canvas").mousemove(function (e) {
handleMouseMove(e);
});
$("#canvas").mouseup(function (e) {
handleMouseUp(e);
});
```

as i am running short of time and i am not able to figure out how this can be done.

Comment: You can't just draw objects onto the canvas *if you want to move them*. You need to create instances of your shape objects and manage those (hit-testing and rendering as required). It is not very complex, but requires a lot more code than you have so far.

Comment: Is there any suggestions or samples that you can share so that i work on those lines?

Comment: How about this: http://simonsarris.com/blog/510-making-html5-canvas-useful

Comment: I am not able to integrate that with my code. Not sure how i can use it.

Answer (score 7):

AFAK, HTML canvas element is simply an array of pixels.

Then drawing/moving/resizing rectangles is, simply again, to keep redrawing canvas.

So first, drawn objects need to be stored (maybe in array).
Second, corresponding mouse events are necessary.
Last, canvas redrawing is required.

Like:

```
var boxes = [];
var tmpBox = null;    
document.getElementById("canvas").onmousedown = function(e) {...};
document.getElementById("canvas").onmouseup = function(e) {...};
document.getElementById("canvas").onmouseout = function(e) {...};
document.getElementById("canvas").onmousemove = function(e) {...};
```

Here is JSFiddle for demo: https://jsfiddle.net/wiany11/p7hxjmsj/14/

Comment: Thanks nice example, How can I use image in canvas background?

Comment: @ShujaathKhan You may be searching for `drawImage` function.

Comment: Thank you very much. I have searched too many stackoverflows and articles, but your answer is the most complete one. Again, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

These 2 tutorials explain what you want:

- http://simonsarris.com/blog/510-making-html5-canvas-useful
- http://simonsarris.com/blog/225-canvas-selecting-resizing-shape

In short you should store the borders of the rectangles yourself and detect when the user clicks in the rectangle or on the border.

First you create an array to store your rectangles in

```
var rectangles = [];
```

Then you make a method  to call every time you want to draw all your rectangles

```
function drawRectangles() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  for(var i = 0; i < rectangles.length; i++) {
    var rect = rectangles[i];
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.rect(rect.startX, rect.startY, rect.endX, rect.endY);
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.closePath();
  }
}
```

In your mouseUp you then push the rectangles you have created to the array

```
function handleMouseUp() {
  ...
  // store the rectangle as an object in your array
  var rectangle = {startX: startX, endX: mouseX, startY: startY, endY: mouseY};
  rectangles.push(rectangle);
  drawRectangles();
}
```

In your other handlers you can then detect if you click in a rectangle of when your mouse will move in one

Comment: Could you share a small code snippet based on my code so that i can have an idea?

Answer (score -1):

You can't just draw objects onto the canvas *if you want to move them*. You need to create instances of your shape objects and manage those (hit-testing and rendering as required). It is not very complex, but requires a lot more code than you have so far.

Try this tutorial: http://simonsarris.com/blog/510-making-html5-canvas-useful

Comment: This tutorial was helpful. But i am not sure how i can implement the same in my code. Can you please help me here?

Comment: With that demo and the other link from the same site http://simonsarris.com/blog/225-canvas-selecting-resizing-shape it will be more about *starting with their sample code* as yours is minimal at the moment.